# Sum of Questionnaire Scores Based on a Domain Table

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created a questionnaire that consists of around 100 questions. Participants are asked to fill them in online, where the items are shuffled each time. These items are separated into 6 domains where, for the sake of easier understanding, let's just call them Domain 1 - 6.

I have them typed in one specific table called "Correspondence", with format like below:

> (An example)
>
> Question No.|Domain
>
> 1　　|Domain A
>
> 2　　|Domain C
>
> 3　　|Domain A
>
> 4　　|Domain B
>
> 5　　|Domain A
>
> 6　　|Domain C

I used Google Form to generate a spreadsheet of RAW data of respondents, where it will help me mark the RAW Scores, for each item on a separate column:

> (An example)
>
> Submission ID|Question 1|Question 2|Question 3|Question 4|Question
>   5|Question 6
>
> Participant 1　|　　2　　|　　3　　|　　5　　 |　　1　　 |　　2　　 |　　4　　 |
>
> Participant 2　|　　5　　|　　4　　|　　5　　 |　　3　　 |　　5　　 |　　1　　 |
>
> Participant 3　|　　1　　|　　1　　|　　1　　 |　　2　　 |　　2　　 |　　2　　 |

The next thing I need to do is generate another table that sums up the Domain totals for each participant. So from the example above, I need to sum 1,3,5 as Domain A, 4 as Domain B and 2 & 6 as Domain C:

> (An example)
>
> Participant 1
>
> |Domain A|Domain B|Domain C|
>
> Total　|　　9　　|　　1　　|　 7 　　|

The hardest thing is to find a proper method to kick start this process. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Either formulas or VBAs would be fine too. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pivot table  ?

Comment: It won't work since the data are not transposed into rows (hence unable to use the grouping function). They are distributed into columns. Each row represents a single participant instead

Moreover, I need to use other formulas in the Excel table later on (such as CountIFS) so I guess Pivot Table doesn't help?

Comment: Do you have full control over all tables/worksheets. So could you add an additional row in the second table, basically where you will put under (or above) each Question the Domain to which they belong? Same for how the question name is written: in the first table this is just 1, 2, ... (under the Question heading), and in the second table this is written in full (Question 1, Question 2, etc.). Could you change this to be the same? Both are not *necessary* and you can use workarounds, but the formula would be easier and better to understand with these changes in input data.

Comment: I don't really have 100% control on the RAW data (which is the 2nd table as I mentioned above). I can do a reference row instead of a column, but if the layout of the produced RAW data changes (the questions are in random order every time someone takes the survey), I will have to manually adjust the reference ROW.

Of course, I can do a formula reference row instead, using simply index/match to auto adjust. But that means I may not be able to maintain the RAW data as a Queried Table (using PowerQuery) since I have to add a row separated from the table itself

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you are able to create a helper row.

First, I created a table to link the question to domain. That is named in my example as "Correspondence". This table is somewhat the answer key. From your description of the problem, you need a table like this to establish which question is associated with the domain/category/point system you want to use.

I then created a helper row for the survey results shown on row 9. This has `=INDEX($B$3:$C$8,MATCH(B$10,$B$3:$B$8,0),2)` in cell B9 as the code to reference the question to the domain. This is immediately above the questions in the example, but you can put it on a separate sheet if needed.

Then you can just sum them up.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(INDIRECT(MATCH($E3,$A:$A,0)&":"&MATCH($E3,$A:$A,0)),$9:$9,F$2))
```

[image]
This formula uses `MATCH`, which returns an integer, inside `INDIRECT` to be used as a dynamic row reference. This will fail if the participant names are not unique. The `SUMIFS` inside the `SUMPRODUCT` allows the row to be treated like an array without using an array formula. So you can recreate the example I have and copy/paste or drag and paste the formulas as you wish.

A different approach may be that you want to sum up the points to the questions first and then do the conversion from question to domain. That way you don't ever have to manipulate the raw data, just the reports. That may be the better approach for you, actually.

Edit: Added information about the formulas and the example.

Comment: If I am looking at this correctly, this is sort of the same suggestion as Peter K commented on my initial question. Basically, adding a reference row along with the questions instead of making another reference table (as you did on Row 9 from screenshot). And then use match indirect match of column & rows as multiple criteria. Did I get that part right?

Comment: If my above understanding of the process is correct, I am assuming that the table from your screenshot A1:C8 is obsolete in the calculation too, yes? (just need to confirm....sorry coz I need to get my head around this)

Comment: @herman925 The table A1:C8 is to link the question number to the domain. The helper row (9) can be on the same table as the raw data or different table. All it does is provide the domain from the question. The first formula in my answer is what goes in cell B9.